# how to validate readLines() input as numeric vs. character in R

Tags: r, vector, type-conversion, numeric

I am coercing a input from `readLines()` which I understand will take any input, character or numeric, and capture it as a character value. I then want to convert the input to a numeric value using `as.numeric()`.

I then want to use a validation test such as `is.numeric()` to check that user has input 5 vs a character string as "five" with the assertthat package.

However when I coerce a character vector (eg. "five") to `as.numeric()` it will produce a NA output. when you test an NA output with `is.numeric()` it will produce a TRUE defeating the whole purpose

How can I validate that a user input a numeric value given that `readLines()` converts everything to a character vector?

```
#both of the below produce TRUE 
  is.numeric(as.numeric("five"))
  is.numeric(as.numeric(5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use `!is.na` to test the result of `as.numeric`. If it failed to convert to valid numeral values, `as.numeric` returns `NA`.

```r
!is.na(as.numeric("five"))
#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
#> [1] FALSE
!is.na(as.numeric("5"))
#> [1] TRUE
!is.na(as.numeric(5))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Or use the regex `^[0-9]+$` to see if the whole input is made up entirely of integers (for testing integers only, not for testing floating point numbers).

```r
grepl("^[0-9]+$", "five")
#> [1] FALSE
grepl("^[0-9]+$", "fi55ve")
#> [1] FALSE
grepl("^[0-9]+$", "356236345")
#> [1] TRUE
grepl("^[0-9]+$", 5235)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks!  I was seeing if there was another way of doing it without using is.na() and your regrex solution provided it. thanks!